# how to get different winning% in decreasing order for number of winners?

Tags: javascript

```js
var result = 0;

function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('w_amount').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('c_size').value;
  var result = 0;
  if (txtFirstNumberValue > 0) {
    result = ((0.15 * parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue)) + parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue)) / parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('e_fee').value = parseFloat(result).toFixed(0);
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('e_fee').value = result;
  }
}
// document.getElementById('e_fee').value = result;    

function isChecked(checkbox, winnerCount) {
  var winner_amount = document.getElementById('w_amount').value;
  var chkMultiEntry = document.getElementById("test5");
  
  if (winner_amount.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('err_w_amount').innerHTML = "Please enter winning amount";
    chkMultiEntry.checked = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('winnerCount').disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    document.getElementById('winner').disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    document.getElementById('err_w_amount').remove();
    return true;
  }
}

var x2;

function set() {
  var set = document.getElementById('winnerCount').value;
  
  if (set.length > sum.length) {
    document.getElementById('err_winnerCount').remove();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('set').innerHTML = "Please enter Set No. of Winners";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Rank &nbsp &nbsp Winning% &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Winning Amount";
  var x = document.getElementById("w_amount").value;
  var w = document.getElementById("c_size").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("winnerCount").value;
  var a = parseInt(x) / parseInt(y);
  var z;
  var c;
  var b = a / x * 100;
  x2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tot');

  if (y <= w) {
    for (z = 1; z <= parseInt(y); z++) {
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += +z + "&nbsp<input type='text'  class='tot' id='perc" + z + "'  value='' onkeyup='getValues(this)'/>&nbsp<input type='text' class='pop' id='val" + z + "' value='Rs." + a + "'/><br>";
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
      x2[i].value = b;
    }
  } else {
    alert('errr');
    $('#err_winnerCount').innerHTML = "Please enter less than contest size";
  }
}

var sharePerc = 0;

function getValues(arg) {
  var id = arg.getAttribute('id');
  var value = this.value;
  var winAmt = document.getElementById("w_amount").value;
  var curPerc = document.getElementById(id).value;

  //var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
  var correspondingId = id.replace("perc", "val");

  var curAmt = curPerc * (winAmt / 100);
  document.getElementById(correspondingId).value = curAmt;

  sharePerc = (100 - curPerc) / (x2.length - 1);
  var shareValue = sharePerc * (winAmt / 100);
  //console.log((100 - curPerc)/(x2.length-1));
  
  for (var i = 1; i < x2.length + 1; i++) {
    if (id != "perc" + i) {
      document.getElementById("perc" + i).value = parseFloat(sharePerc).toFixed(0);
      document.getElementById("val" + i).value = parseFloat(shareValue).toFixed(0);
    }
  }
  //document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="register" method="post" id="userForm">
  <ul class="demo">
    </br>
    <li>Winning Amount:<input type="number" id="w_amount" onkeyup="sum()" onblur="validate()" name="wamount"><span class="err" id="err_w_amount"></span></li>
    </br>
    <li>Contest Size:<input type="number" id="c_size" onkeyup="sum()" onblur="checkTextField(this);" name="csize" value="2"></li>
    </br>
    <li>Entry Fee:<input type="number" id="e_fee" name="cname" onkeyup="sum()" value=""></li>
    </br>
    <!-- <li><input type="checkbox" id="MultiEntry"><p>Join this contest with multiple teams</p></li></br> -->
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="test5" onchange="return isChecked(this, 'winnerCount');" /><label for="test5">Customize Winnings</label></li>
    <li><span class="inTxt">Set No. of Winners</span>
      <input type="number" maxlength="5" placeholder="min 2 &amp; max 100" name="Name" id="winnerCount" disabled="disabled" /> </br>
      </br>
      <input class="W_set" type="button" name="button" value="Set" id="winner" disabled="disabled" onclick="set()"></input><span class="err" id="err_winnerCount"></span></li>
    </br>
  </ul>
</form>
<div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
</div>
```

// firstly when giving winning amount and contest size we get the entry fee and after check in customize winning it will enable the set number of winners and set button.In set number of winners the input should be less than the contest size but while entering the greater than contest size it will not showing error message and after clicking set button we get a list of winners in this the winning % should be decreasing order while changing the default winning % of first text box but in my code while changing the second text box it changes the first text box also. if possible please know me how to solve this.

Comment: The markup is invalid. It's `<br />` and not `</br>` and `<br />` is not a valid child element of `<ul>`

Comment: Also post the code of validate() function. It gives error on blur event.

Comment: that is the code only as i written. Please make changes if anything wrong

Comment: What is sum.length inside set() function? @JyothibabuNanipini

Comment: sum.length is contest size (set number of winners must be less than contest size).

Comment: please validate and not to exceed greater than the contest size.and also do while changing the set number of winners and by clicking the set button the table should get without page refresh, i'm tried but not working.

Comment: I have not completely understood your problem. So we will solve it step by step. "In set number of winners the input should be less than the contest size" we will solve this problem first. I will post the answer and then you can comment what next I should solve. @JyothibabuNanipini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var result = 0;

function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('w_amount').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('c_size').value;
  var result = 0;
  if (txtFirstNumberValue > 0) {
    result = ((0.15 * parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue)) + parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue)) / parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('e_fee').value = parseFloat(result).toFixed(0);
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('e_fee').value = result;
  }
}
// document.getElementById('e_fee').value = result;    

function isChecked(checkbox, winnerCount) {
  var winner_amount = document.getElementById('w_amount').value;
  var chkMultiEntry = document.getElementById("test5");
  
  if (winner_amount.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('err_w_amount').innerHTML = "Please enter winning amount";
    chkMultiEntry.checked = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('winnerCount').disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    document.getElementById('winner').disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    document.getElementById('err_w_amount').remove();
    return true;
  }
}

var x2;

function set() {
  $('#err_winnerCount').html("");
  var set = document.getElementById('winnerCount').value;
  var contestSize = document.getElementById('c_size').value;
  
  if (set > contestSize) {
    $('#err_winnerCount').html("");
  } else {
    //document.getElementById('set').innerHTML = "Please enter Set No. of Winners";
  }
  
  var x = document.getElementById("w_amount").value;
  var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("c_size").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("winnerCount").value);
  var a = parseInt(x) / parseInt(y);
  var z;
  var c;
  var b = a / x * 100;
  x2 = document.getElementsByClassName('tot');

  if (y <= w) {
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Rank &nbsp &nbsp Winning% &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Winning Amount";
    var demoTableBody = document.getElementById("demo_table").tBodies[0];
    demoTableBody.innerHTML = "";
    //console.log(demoTableBody.innerHTML);
    for (z = 1; z <= parseInt(y); z++) {
      //console.log(demoTableBody.children.length);
      var rowIndex = demoTableBody.children.length + 1;
      var newRow = "<td>"+rowIndex+"</td>";
      newRow += "<td><input type='text'  class='tot' id='perc" + rowIndex + "'  value='' onkeyup='getValues(this)'/><span class = 'perc_error_spn' id='perc_error" + rowIndex + "'></span></td>";
      newRow += "<td><input type='text' class='pop' id='val" + rowIndex + "' value='Rs." + a + "'/></td>";
      demoTableBody.innerHTML += newRow;
      //document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += +z + "&nbsp<input type='text'  class='tot' id='perc" + z + "'  value='' onkeyup='getValues(this)'/>&nbsp<input type='text' class='pop' id='val" + z + "' value='Rs." + a + "'/><br>";
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
      x2[i].value = b;
    }
  } else {
 alert("errr");
    $('#err_winnerCount').html("Please enter less than contest size");
  }
}

var sharePerc = 0;

function getValues(arg) {
// clear all error messages.
  var errorSpans = document.getElementsByClassName("perc_error_spn");  
  for(var i = 0; i < errorSpans.length; i++){
      errorSpans[i].innerHTML = "";
  }
  var id = arg.getAttribute('id');
  var row_index = arg.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var value = this.value;
  var winAmt = document.getElementById("w_amount").value;
  var tmp = 0;
  var previousWinnersPercentage = [];
  var nextWinnersPercentage = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < row_index; i++){
    tmp += parseFloat(document.getElementById("perc" + i).value);
    previousWinnersPercentage[previousWinnersPercentage.length] = tmp;
  }
  for(var i = row_index + 1 ; i <= x2.length; i++){
    nextWinnersPercentage[nextWinnersPercentage.length] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("perc" + i).value);
  }
  //winAmt -= tmp;
  var curPerc = document.getElementById(id).value;

   sharePerc = (100 - tmp - curPerc) / (x2.length - row_index);
    var isInvalidInput = isBiggerThanPreviousPercentage(previousWinnersPercentage,curPerc);
   if(!isInvalidInput){
    isInvalidInput = isLesserThanPreviousPercentage(nextWinnersPercentage,curPerc);
   }
   if((sharePerc <= 0 && x2.length > 1) || isInvalidInput){
       var errorSpan = id.replace("perc", "perc_error");
       document.getElementById(errorSpan).innerHTML = "Invalid input";
       return;
   }
  //var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
  var correspondingId = id.replace("perc", "val");

  var curAmt = curPerc * (winAmt / 100);
  document.getElementById(correspondingId).value = curAmt;

  sharePerc = (100 - tmp - curPerc) / (x2.length - row_index);
  var shareValue = sharePerc * (winAmt / 100);
  //console.log((100 - curPerc)/(x2.length-1));
  
  for (var i = row_index; i <= x2.length; i++) {
    if (id != "perc" + i) {
      document.getElementById("perc" + i).value = parseFloat(sharePerc).toFixed(0);
      document.getElementById("val" + i).value = parseFloat(shareValue).toFixed(0);
    }
  }
  //document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
}

function reorderPercentage(){
  var demoTableBody = document.getElementById("demo_table").tBodies[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < demoTableBody.children.length; i++){
    var percentageInput = demoTableBody.children[i].querySelector(".tot");
    //console.log(percentageInput.value);
    var row = percentageInput.parentNode.parentNode,
        sibling = row.nextElementSibling,
        parent = row.parentNode;
    var siblingPercentageValue = "";
    //console.log(sibling);
    if(sibling != null){
      siblingPercentageValue = sibling.querySelector(".tot").value;
    }
    if(percentageInput.value < siblingPercentageValue){
      parent.insertBefore(sibling,row);
    }
  }
}

function isBiggerThanPreviousPercentage(array,value) { 
  var result = false;
  result = array.some(function (e) {
      if(value > e){
        return true;
      }
  });
  return result;
}

function isLesserThanPreviousPercentage(array,value) { 
  var result = false;
  result = array.some(function (e) {
      if(value < e){
        return true;
      }
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="register" method="post" id="userForm">
  <ul class="demo">
    </br>
    <li>Winning Amount:<input type="number" id="w_amount" onkeyup="sum()"  name="wamount"><span class="err" id="err_w_amount"></span></li>
    </br>
    <li>Contest Size:<input type="number" id="c_size" onkeyup="sum()" onblur="checkTextField(this);" name="csize" value="3"></li>
    </br>
    <li>Entry Fee:<input type="number" id="e_fee" name="cname" onkeyup="sum()" value=""></li>
    </br>
    <!-- <li><input type="checkbox" id="MultiEntry"><p>Join this contest with multiple teams</p></li></br> -->
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="test5" onchange="return isChecked(this, 'winnerCount');" /><label for="test5">Customize Winnings</label></li>
    <li><span class="inTxt">Set No. of Winners</span>
      <input type="number" maxlength="5" placeholder="min 2 &amp; max 100" name="Name" id="winnerCount" disabled="disabled" /> </br>
      </br>
      <input class="W_set" type="button" name="button" value="Set" id="winner" disabled="disabled" onclick="set()"/><span class="err" id="err_winnerCount"></span>
      <input type="button" value="Reorder" onclick="reorderPercentage();"/>
    </br>
  </ul>
</form>
<div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
  <table id="demo_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Winning %</th>
        <th>Winning Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">10 Winners</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Prize</th> 
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2-5</td>
    <td>500</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6-10</td>
    <td>100</td>
    
  </tr>
</table> 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

If you input number of winners greater than contest size it will prompt an alert box. Check and let me know that is it working or not?

Due to below code both the text boxes are modified simultaneously. 
If you can explain the below code, why you are using this

```
for (var i = 1; i < x2.length + 1; i++) {
    if (id != "perc" + i) {
      document.getElementById("perc" + i).value = parseFloat(sharePerc).toFixed(0);
      document.getElementById("val" + i).value = parseFloat(shareValue).toFixed(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: while changing the set number of winners it will adding to the last table...@lalit

Comment: I didn't get you?

Comment: hi lalit, when getting the table for the given values after that while changing the set number of winners value less than before given value . it will adding to the down and not getting the new table. please check once.

Comment: thanks lalit, how can we remove error message after giving correct value on  set number of winners

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini Check again.

Comment: and one more thing is while changing the winning % its not taking the decresing order means( it will taking like this 1) 20%, 2) 30%..3)50%......                    i want in decreasing order 1)50% 2)30% 3)20%.. please validate this condition also.

Comment: For that we need a button or something to reorder the table rows. If we do it this way it will be better. If we do it on key press it will be difficult to do that.

Comment: I can't think of any solution right now. But if we reorder rows on key press the textbox will also be reordered and then user might get confuse while entering the data. I suggest it will not be a good approach to do this task. You should go for button option.

Comment: can you know that..if so do please.

Comment: You mean Button approach?

Comment: hi lalit, Is it possible to do that button approach.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that. I will update the answer in sometime.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini I have added the reorder functionality. For now I have not refactored the ranks, so that you can see that rows are actually reordering.

Comment: but the rank is not ordered .ok, i had a thought, can validate the winning %  less than the above one by the error message like not valid.

Comment: I have mentioned in my previous comment that I have not changed the ranks. Is there any other problem that you are facing?

Comment: yeah, can you do validation like this, suppose  if we give contest size 2 and no.of winners is also 2 then the winning amount is 100.autometically the winning % should be 50-50. in this case while changing the winning % of 1st one is less than the 2nd one it should be not valid similarly this should be vise-versa. is it ok .

Comment: But yesterday you have said to validate the same thing. That if user changes first winner's value it should validate the data.

Comment: in suppose of two wiiners first one should be not less than 2nd one and 2nd one should be not greater than first one.

Comment: similarly think that if increasing winners size it should be like that while changing the winning % of last two rows.

Comment: hello lalit, is there any solution.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini I have updated the code. Check and let me know. I think you won't need the re-order function now.

Comment: yes lalit now don't need the reorder function and thank you very much lalit.

Comment: hi lalit, one more question for you. After setting the winning % , I want a winner table like this in the code.

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more?

Comment: i want this function in another page.

Comment: On hover of same button?

Comment: sorry, I edited in the previous code . that the functionality should be work on other page.

Comment: hi lalit, is any solution is there.